# PowerPivotConfigTool has stopped working

Tags: powerpivot

when I run PowerPivot Configuration tool for the second time(first it ran perfectly), I get this error message while it's in the `Examining your system. Please wait...` state.

[image: powerpivot]
[image: powerpivot has stopped working]

Here is what I've got from event viewer:

> Application: PowerPivotSPAddinConfiguration.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>   Stack:
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr, System.Object[], System.Object, System.Object[] ByRef)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my "Hijri Calendar" Package that I've bought from a company. I've found this out by "Debug The Program" Option in the error window. here is what I got from visual studio:

> System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Globalization.HijriCalendar.GetYear(DateTime time)
>          at System.DateTimeFormat.FormatCustomized(DateTime dateTime, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, TimeSpan offset)
>          at System.DateTimeFormat.Format(DateTime dateTime, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, TimeSpan offset)
>          at System.Management.Automation.MshLog.GetLogContext(ExecutionContext executionContext, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Severity severity)
>          at System.Management.Automation.MshLog.LogProviderLifecycleEvent(ExecutionContext executionContext, String providerName, ProviderState providerState)
>          at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.AddProvider(Type implementingType, String name, String helpFileName, PSSnapInInfo psSnapIn, PSModuleInfo module)
>          at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.AddProvider(ProviderConfigurationEntry providerConfig)
>          at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.UpdateProviders()
>          at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigurationEntryCollection`1.Update(Boolean force)
>          at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfiguration.Bind(ExecutionContext executionContext)
>          at System.Management.Automation.AutomationEngine..ctor(PSHost hostInterface, RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration, InitialSessionState iss)
>          at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace.DoOpenHelper()
>          at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.CoreOpen(Boolean syncCall)
>          at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Configuration.Tool.PowerShellCommandExecutor..ctor()
>          at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Configuration.Tool.Utils.IsSingleMachineFarm()
>          at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Configuration.Tool.ScenarioManager.SystemCheck()
>          at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.Configuration.Tool.ScenarioSelection.validateWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
>          at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>     InnerException:

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend uninstall & reinstall the

**PowerPivot Configuration Tools:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213173.aspx.

or maybe

**PowerPivot for SharePoint Add-in:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218792.aspx

Comment: I've done it, doesn't work. same result.